# GetAppliedGPOList and pGuidExtension value

Tags: c, winapi, gpo

I'm trying to use the `GetAppliedGPOList` function, but cannot find/understand what the `pGuidExtension` should be.

Here's the simple code so far:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <UserEnv.h>

int wmain(int argc, WCHAR *argv[])
{
    //GetAppliedGPOList
    DWORD flags = GPO_LIST_FLAG_MACHINE;
    LPCWSTR machineName = NULL; //Local computer is used
    PSID sidUser = NULL;

    GUID *pGuidExtension;   //What is the GUID of the extension?

    PGROUP_POLICY_OBJECT *ppGPOList;


    return 0;
}
```

Cannot run the function because I need to send that value.

Any example about the `pGuidExtension` value?

I did search here but found nothing about it.

Thank you.

Comment: the guids is listed at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\GPExtensions`. for example - [*Group Policy Client Side Extension List*](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mempson/2010/12/01/group-policy-client-side-extension-list/). the `GetAppliedGPOList` is looked under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\History\{GuidExtension}` key

Answer (score 0):

The guids is listed at

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\GPExtensions
```

For example - [Group Policy Client Side Extension List](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mempson/2010/12/01/group-policy-client-side-extension-list/). The `GetAppliedGPOList` is looked under

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\History\{GuidExtension}
```

key